# Invalid flow for client: Implicit. identity server authorization

Tags: php, identityserver3

I'm trying to authorize an app using identiy server, but when I try to log in it says that `The client application is not known or is not authorized`. I'm trying to authorize with this endpoint and credentials, using a function that returns an string to redirect.

```
function create_login_url(){
return "indentiy-dev12:8443/connect/authorize?"
    ."client_id=" ."MyClient". "&" . 
"scope=" . urlencode(openid profile read write email roles) . "&" .
"redirect_uri=" . "http://localhost:8080/my-page/validate.php" . "&" .
"response_mode=" . "form_post" . "&" .
"state=" . time() . rand() . "&" .
"nonce=" . rand() . time() . "&" .
"reponse_type=" . urlencode(id_token token);
 }
```

The client was created with this info:

```
        {
            ClientName = "My Client",
            Enabled = true,
            ClientId = "MyClient",
            ClientSecrets = new List<ClientSecret>
            {
                new ClientSecret("MyClient".Sha256())
            },
            RedirectUris = new List<string>
            {
                "http://192.168.0.30/my-page/validate.php",
                "http://localhost:8080/my-page/validate.php",
            },

            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
            {
               "http://192.168.0.30/my-page/validate.php",
               "http://localhost:8080/my-page/validate.php",
            },

            Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner
        }
```

This is what the log says:

```
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 9/25/2017 5:35:14 PM +00:00 -- Start authorize request client validation
Debug: [Cache]: 9/25/2017 5:35:14 PM +00:00 -- Cache hit: MyClient
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 9/25/2017 5:35:14 PM +00:00 -- Invalid flow for client: Implicit
 {
  "ClientId": "MyClient",
  "ClientName": "My Client",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8080/my-page/validate.php",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://192.168.0.30/my-page/validate.php",
    "http://localhost:8080/my-page/validate.php"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "user.fabio",
  "ResponseType": "id_token token",
  "ResponseMode": "form_post",
  "Flow": "Implicit",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile read write email roles",
  "State": "15063609141165646676",
  "Nonce": "15954663491506360914",
  "SessionId": "33e89e5746b59e895c5d6edf6b5220b4",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "MyClient",
    "scope": "openid profile read write email roles",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8080/my-page/validate.php",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "state": "15063609141165646676",
    "nonce": "15954663491506360914",
    "response_type": "id_token token"
  }
}
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Events]: 9/25/2017 5:35:14 PM +00:00 -- {
  "Category": "Endpoints",
  "Name": "Endpoint failure",
  "EventType": "Failure",
  "Id": 3001,
  "Message": "unauthorized_client",
  "Details": {
    "EndpointName": "authorize"
  },
  "Context": {
    "ActivityId": "c30c1550-4cf7-4527-8d09-b42e2557ffaa",
    "TimeStamp": "2017-09-25T17:35:14.1943477+00:00",
    "ProcessId": 696,
    "MachineName": "machine-name",
    "RemoteIpAddress": "192.168.70.28",
    "SubjectId": "user.fabio"
  }
}
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 9/25/2017 5:35:14 PM +00:00 -- End authorize request
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 9/25/2017 6:33:38 PM +00:00 -- AuthorizationCodeStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 9/25/2017 6:33:38 PM +00:00 -- TokenHandleStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 9/25/2017 6:33:38 PM +00:00 -- ConsentStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 9/25/2017 6:33:38 PM +00:00 -- RefreshTokenStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Events]: 9/25/2017 6:33:39 PM +00:00 -- {
  "Category": "Information",
  "Name": "Signing certificate validation success",
  "EventType": "Information",
  "Id": 4012,
  "Details": {
    "SigningCertificateName": "CN=idsrv3test",
    "SigningCertificateExpiration": "2020-01-20T16:00:00-06:00"
  },
  "Context": {
    "TimeStamp": "2017-09-25T18:33:39.0033098+00:00",
    "ProcessId": 8468,
    "MachineName": "machine-name"
  }
}
```

The server that i'm trying to login is not in my pc. There're another clients that can log in successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login request is asking for an identity token and an access token. This translates to the implicit grant type.

Your client entry however, is configured for the ROPC grant type. ROPC is not *really* authentication, nor is it OpenID Connect, so you can't get identity tokens using it. This is why you are getting the error message from IdentityServer.

You'll need to change the clients flow to `Flows.Implicit`

P.S. It looks like you're using a really old version of IdentityServer. They dropped the Thinktecture prefix years ago. You might want to look into that.

Comment: The thing is that there’re other clients using this flow and It works for them. There’s nothing else It could be ?

Comment: Their requests will look something like this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.1, whilst yours look like http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest

Comment: Using the information you have provided, there is nothing else this could be.

Comment: I tried to made the request like this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.1  but I get `unsupported_response_type` error.

Comment: I made some corrections to the request and chaged the flow to implicti. Thanks.